# How can I select the indexes where my dataframe has more than two entries?

Tags: pandas

I have a multilevel indexed frame. It looks like

```
actor               title_year  sum count
50 Cent               2005.0    30981850.0  1
A.J. Buckley          2015.0    123070338.0 1
Aaliyah               2002.0    30307804.0  1
Aasif Mandvi          2008.0    13214030.0  1
Abbie Cornish           2009.0  4440055.0   1
```

Here, `actor` and `title_year` form a multi index.  How can I slice out the entries which have multi_index where `actor` spans more than `n` years?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration):

```
print (df)
                                  sum  count
actor         title_year                    
50 Cent       2005.0       30981850.0      1
              2006.0       30981850.0      1
              2007.0       30981850.0      1
A.J. Buckley  2015.0      123070338.0      1
Aaliyah       2002.0       30307804.0      1
              2002.0       30307804.0      1
              2004.0       30307804.0      1
Aasif Mandvi  2008.0       13214030.0      1
Abbie Cornish 2009.0        4440055.0      1
```

If need remove all `actor`s with `length` more as `2`:

```
df1 = df.groupby(level='actor').filter(lambda x: len(x) < 3)
print (df1)
                                  sum  count
actor         title_year                    
A.J. Buckley  2015.0      123070338.0      1
Aasif Mandvi  2008.0       13214030.0      1
Abbie Cornish 2009.0        4440055.0      1
```

If need remove all `actor`s with `length` of unique values in level `title_year` more as `2`:

```
df2 = df.groupby(level='actor')
        .filter(lambda x: x.index.get_level_values('title_year').nunique() < 3)
print (df2)
                                  sum  count
actor         title_year                    
A.J. Buckley  2015.0      123070338.0      1
Aaliyah       2002.0       30307804.0      1
              2002.0       30307804.0      1
              2004.0       30307804.0      1
Aasif Mandvi  2008.0       13214030.0      1
Abbie Cornish 2009.0        4440055.0      1
```